# Read on pipe with threads

Tags: c++, pthreads, pipe

I am writing a program with threads interacting with each other using pipes. In my program the main thread creates an application thread and a protocol thread. Two pipes are created for the protocol thread and it is blocked on the read on pipes. The application thread writes to one of the pipes of the protocol thread.

Now I have 3 threads (main thread, 1 protocol thread, 1 application thread). After application thread writes to one of the protocol pipes, the protocol thread is not reading the data immediately. It reads the data if I press enter twice/thrice. Not sure whats going on here.

The syntax might not be exactly right.. but just gives an idea

```
// application thread
char* data = new char[100];
for (i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
{
    data[i] = 'm';
}

write(fd, &data, 100);
sleep(10);

//protocol thread
while(1)
{
    char data1[100];
    read(fd1, &data1, 100);
}
```

Why is the protocol thread not reading the data immediately. I saw there is no buffering involved with the pipes (fflush doesnt help). So what does "enter" (return) do to make the thread unblock and read the data..

Can anyone please help me with this. Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using pipes between threads? There are easier solutions using conditional waits.

Comment: Yeah.. The requirement says to use the pipes.

Comment: How are you opening the pipe?  Show more code

Comment: Is it homework then?  If so please tag it as such.

Comment: Protocol and Application obejcts recieve the file desc when they are created. int fd[2]; pipe(fd); Protocol(fd[0]) Application(fd[1])

Comment: @MooingDuck: Its not exactly the homework.

Comment: I am passing the file descriptors that I used while creating the pipe to different objects and storing in a different variable (same type though), and using the variables to read/write.. Does that matter?

Comment: How do you know that it isn't immediate?  Are you using pthreads, or are you writing and reading from the same thread?